# Google+ api sharing interactive posts twice

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus

In my android app, I would like to let users share interactive posts. So I use the code given in https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/share/interactive-post

```
PlusShare.Builder builder = new PlusShare.Builder(this, monPlusClient);
builder.addCallToAction("DISCOVER", Uri.parse(target), ident);
builder.setContentUrl(Uri.parse(target));
builder.setContentDeepLinkId(ident, topic.getNomPeintre(), desc,
            Uri.parse(topic.getLien()));
builder.setText(texte + " #Art");
Intent shareIntent = builder.getIntent();
startActivityForResult(shareIntent, SHAREGPLUS_REQUEST_CODE);
```

I have a fully operationnal connection with Google+ API (keys are OK).

**The problem is that I can see my post two times inside Google+.**

Why ?

My test environment :

- Nexus 7 physical device under Android 4.4.2 build KOT49H
- Google Play Services version 4.1.32 (978161-30)
- Android SDK Manager : Google Play Services version 14

Answer (score 1):

Facing similar issue. This is happening due to having both setContentUrl and setContentDeepLinkId. You can use one base on your requirement such as interactive or non-interative share content.

Comment: I am not sure to understand, if I don't use setContentUrl, there is an error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content URL is required for interactive posts.

Comment: Yes, If you need interactive post then use setContentUri and don't use setContentDeepLinkId(). Google-plus retrieves content from the link you have provided and generates an interactive post of it.